# Mod_Feed removing the strip image function what do the True & False do?

Tags: module, images, jhtml, feeds

I want to remove the strip image function from mod_feed in the administrator area.

mod_feed/tmpl/default.php at line 118

```
// Strip the images.
$text = JFilterOutput::stripImages($text);
$text = JHtml::_('string.truncate', $text, $params->get('word_count', 0), true, false);
echo str_replace('&apos;', "'", $text);
```

When I comment(//) the first `$text` the images don't show up.

When I comment(//) the second `$text` as well then the images are visible.

But can someone tell me what the `true` and `false` do that come after `('word_count', 0), true, false);`
And how should this be rewritten that it allows the images and still do the word count.

PS: I know editing a Joomla Module goes away after update. It is just learning for me.

PS2: Changing the last false to true makes the images show. But how to find out what it is pointed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments for `JHtmlString::truncate()` are:

```
string   $text       The text to truncate.
integer  $length     The maximum length of the text.
boolean  $noSplit    Don't split a word if that is where the cutoff occurs (default: true).
boolean  $allowHtml  Allow HTML tags in the output, and close any open tags (default: true).
```

Change the last argument to `true` or omit it (it defaults to `true`) to allow HTML tags.

https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JHtmlString.html#method_truncate

Comment: Thank you very much for this clear answer. But especially thanks for the link I am a hundred percent sure this is going to help me a lot in the future. Cheers mate!